# Notation for set of all closed sets

Tags: general-topology, notation

Is there a common notation for the set of all closed sets of a topological space?

I have been using $(X,\tau)$ to denote a topological space with $\tau$ being the topology, set of all open sets. I was wondering if there is something like that this is used widely but for all the closed sets.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: I think it is just called the topology when it is clear that you are specifying the topology by specifying the closed sets instead of the open sets. I've seen the Zarisky topology defined this way.

Comment: You can define a topology in terms of its closed sets, so if you state at the start that this is the definition of a topology you will be using, you can just stick to $(X,\tau)$.

Comment: $\tau^c$  :-). ${}{}$

Comment: I like the $\tau^c$

Comment: @copper.hat I rather like that.

Comment: I've encountered the notation $(X,\mathcal F)$ where the $\mathcal F$ means *fermé*, which is the French word for *closed*.

Comment: $\tau^{\hat{\dot{c}}}$ the hat is to show its not a time derivative of a complement of $\tau$.

Comment: My first real exposure to topology was in Math 202A in Berkeley taught by a delightful fellow named Shoshichi Kobayashi. I remember him saying "a set is not like a door, it can be open and closed at the same time". Funny how things like that stick in your head.

Comment: @copper.hat One of my teachers also said that... Fact: there is a somewhat obscure class of topological spaces called "door spaces" where (by definition) every subset of it is closed or open (or both, of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such standard notation. The safest approach is to let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ (or $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$, etc.) be a topological space and then explicitly to name the collection of closed sets, e.g., by letting $\mathscr{F}=\{X\setminus U:U\in\tau\}$.

Since $F$ (from French *fermé*) is one of the letters that I conventionally use for closed sets, I’m likely to use $\mathscr{F}$ or $\mathscr{C}$ (for *closed*) for the collection of closed sets unless those letters have been pre-empted.

Comment: When we want to consider the collection of closed (or more usually non-empty, closed) subsets of a space $X$ as a space in its own right (giving it a new topology derived somehow from the one on $X$), the collection is called the hyperspace of $X$. Different notations exist for this, most commonly $H(X)$ and $2^X$. The so-called Vietoris topology is (IMHO) the most natural of the topologies on this hyperspace.

Comment: @Henno: I like Som Naimpally’s name for topologies of the Vietoris type: *hit-and-miss* topologies.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott don't you mean $\mathcal{F} = \{2^X \backslash U : U\in\tau \}$?

Comment: @jadn: No: the complement of $U$ is $X\setminus U$. Assuming that by $2^X$ you mean $\wp(X)$, $2^X\setminus U=2^X$, since $U$ is not a **subset** of $2^X$.