# What is the set of closed subsets called?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, terminology

For any set $X$, the set of all open subsets is called a topology on/of $X$.

Is there an equivalent word for the collection of closed subsets? I tried looking at Wikipedia and searching on SE but didn't find anything. I haven't heard anything like this though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notation for set of all closed sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414289/notation-for-set-of-all-closed-sets)

Comment: Not really, but it does tell me that my quest is hopeless :)

Comment: You could try using "ygolopot" and see if the term sticks :)

Comment: For a Moore closure I've seen the notation of Moore collection being used for their "closed sets". As topological closure is usually called Kuratowski closure, maybe you can get away with calling it Kuratowski collection

Answer (score 1):

There is no special name for the closed sets per se, as noted in the comments. But if we use these closed (non-empty) sets as elements of a new space (and put a new topology on that), the term "hyperspace" of $X$ is used (sometimes denoted $H(X)$ or $2^X$ or $\exp(X)$ as well). But that denotes a new topological space (constructed from $X$) so is probably not what you wanted..

Comment: It is also sometimes used to refer only to *compact* subsets of $X$.

Comment: Is this somewhat related to creating an affine scheme from an affine variety? As in Hartshorne's proposition 2.6?