# Notation for the set difference of a set and a family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would like to denote the set difference of a set $X$ and a family of sets $C$ by
$$
X \setminus C
=
\{X \setminus A ~|~ A \in C\}
$$
allowing the abuse of notation. This idea is inspired by the post by [user43138](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/414289/334795).

For example, it can be used to concisely denote the collection of closed sets $V$ of $X$ from topology $\tau$, i.e., $V = X \setminus \tau$ according to the notation.

If it is unnatural, is there a nice well-known notation for this purpose?

Comment: I've not seen that notation, but it's natural enough so that you can use it if you define it for your reader when you first need it.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you for the advice!